# vim-enhanced is install but visualextra is disabled?

Tags: vim

env : centos7

installed vim :

- vim-filesystem-7.4.160-6.el7_6.x86_64
- vim-minimal-7.4.160-6.el7_6.x86_64
- vim-common-7.4.160-6.el7_6.x86_64
- vim-enhanced-7.4.160-6.el7_6.x86_64

---

I wanted to use multi line insert using visualblock.
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> worked but <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> didn't.

I checked plugins with `:version`

and it says `-visualextra`

How do I change it to `+visualextra` ?

Comment: I don't think you should have both `vim-minimal` and `vim-enhanced`.

Comment: How are you invoking Vim? If you're typing "vi" you'll get the minimal Vim, but if you type "vim" you should get the enhanced Vim with +visualextra.